# Error While running multiple queries in .net sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc

Let us consider the following connection string which connects sql server through odbc driver as

```
"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=xxx.xx.xx.xx,xxxx;Database=mydata;Uid=xx;Pwd=xxxxxx;"
```

**Database type: Sql server**

**Driver:sql server-ODBC native client 10.0**

**Provider type: System.Data.Odbc**

In which i am executing 50 commands through odbc connection...

In that 50 first 25 in connection string 1 and rest 25 in connection string 2.

There by

when i am executing those command around 35 commands executed well after that i got the **error** as

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unspecified error occurred on SQL Server. Connection may have been terminated by the server.
```

for rest all queries executed after that and

**Stack trace:**

```
  at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at testprovision.CommonDAL.ExecuteNonQuery(String connectionString, CommandType cmdType, String cmdText, OdbcParameter[] commandParameters) in
```

**Execute non query loop Code** which i used was

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string connectionString, CommandType cmdType, string cmdText, params OdbcParameter[] commandParameters)
{
    int val = 0;
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
    try
    {
       using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
       {
           CommonCommand(cmd, conn, null, cmdType, cmdText, commandParameters);
           val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           cmd.Parameters.Clear();
           conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    return val;
}
```

What i have to do now in order to solve the issue

Waiting for your responses..

Answer (score 1):

So you are opening conn in CommonCommand?
In my mind that is a bad practice.
Open and Close in one place.
Right now if ExecuteNonQuery(); fails it goes to Catch and the conn is not closed.

Try this pattern

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
try
{
   conn.Open();
   using (OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand)
   {
       // do NOT have CommonCommand open the connection.  
       // change CommonCommand to not even pass the connection
       CommonCommand(cmd, null, cmdType, cmdText, commandParameters);
       val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       // cmd.Parameters.Clear();   
       // don't need to clear or dipose it will do so when it falls out of scope     
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```